# jQuery Animate width to the left and up

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, direction

I'm trying to animate an image's width and height properties.  Currently the image (as expected) animates to the right and down, however I'd like for the animation to occur to the left and upwards.  Here's my current code :

http://jsfiddle.net/7UbYy/

I've read a few other posts on this subject which all refer to setting a marginLeft or left property but I can't seem to get the desired effect.  I need the image to animate to the left and upwards while remaining in place.  Let me know if this is possible...I can't seem to think of a way to do it right now..

Thanks in advance.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That fiddle is not working for me.

Try settings `#meet_team img { bottom:0; right:0; }`

Or setting the width and height of the `<li>` and setting `text-align: right; vertical-align: baseline;`

Comment: The #meet_team img suggestion worked perfect.  For all future reference, what I did was set the img to absolute positioning with a bottom of 0 and a right of 0.  The image was contained within an <li> element that had relative positioning.